# Adding Spaces to Numerals

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a space between any numbers that are passed over. Basically if `$var2` was `1028` I want it to add a space so that it becomes `1 0 2 8`. I only want it to add it for numerals though and not letters. I only need it to do it on `var2`-`var5` and nothing above that. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
$apikey = $_GET['apikey'];
$campaign = $_GET['campaign'];
$phone = $_GET['number'];
$delay = $_GET['delay'];
$name = $_GET['var1'];
$var2 = $_GET['var2'];
$var3 = $_GET['var3'];
$var4 = $_GET['var4'];
$var5 = $_GET['var5'];
```

Comment: Do you have anything that you have started that isn't working?

Comment: What does "passed over" here mean?

Comment: It works right now, but I am basically using this for text to speech. When it's passed over as 1028 it says one-thousand-twenty-eight when I want it to say one-zero-two-eight. What I mean from passed over is on form submit, it gets from the form fields.

Answer (score 3):

```
$var2 = implode(' ',str_split($_GET['var2']));
```

Comment: We'd still have to check that `var2` is an integer, though.

Comment: That would still need to be checked anyway, irrespective of the method used to split the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick function which will make your life a lot easier.

```
function preg_add( $content, $regex, $replace = '${1}' ) {
   return trim( preg_replace( $content, $regex, $replace ) );
}
```

To use it you simply do; `$var2 = preg_add( $var2, '/([0-9])/', '${1} ' );`

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 2; $i <= 5; $i++)
{
    $val = $_GET["var" . $i];
    $pattern = '/\d/g';
    $replacement = '${1} ';
    $newVal = preg_replace(pattern, replacement, $val);
}
```